# django urlencode multiple variables in template

Tags: django

I want to url encode the following inside template

{{address.street}} {{address.city}} {address.state}}

is there anyway to do this on the template side and place it into an href( i prefer NOT to combine them on the server side):

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=<!-- OVER HERE --!>">Map It</a>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr={{address.street|urlencode}} {{address.city|urlencode}} {{address.state|urlencode}}">
```

I'm not sure how you wanted to combine them, I just used a space.  Or:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr={% filter urlencode %}{{address.street}} {{address.city}} {{address.state}}{% endfilter %}">
```